# How to an async function in a child page widget before it gets built when it is navigated to?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and working on an application with a dashboard and several pages.

When the app is first opens the dashboard opens up with a bottom navigator to the other pages. On each of the other pages an async http request method is called to retrieve information and populate the page.

However, I want to show a summary of the information collected from these pages on the dashboard when the app first opens up. Is there a way to do this without navigating to any of the other pages or calling all the request methods from the dashboard page?

I've tried callbacks, but these need an active trigger on the child pages and I'm looking to load in all the info before the user even navigates to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to have acces to all that data is to either fetch the data in your dashboard file or fetch the date inside the void main function.

You can however put the functions in separate files and import them.

If it's a small application you can pass the data on as prop to the child components.

If it's a bigger application with more data, you can then use Bloc or flutter_redux to globally store the data so you can acces it in other files aswel.

Bloc:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

Redux:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_redux

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem like they're a simple way to get all the data upfront with minimum requests. Will test out this implementation.